# How could I see view count on questions I answered?

Tags: feature-request, views

I tried to find similar question on meta, but without result.

I want to know which questions I answered are most popular to improve them and make them more helpful for new viewers.

Comment: I remember seeing a query for this in the data explorer. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: This is tough, not sure it can be done with the current Advanced Search options.  The `views:xxx` option overrides the `is:answer` option (and that still wouldn't get you there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

Although it's not perfect, here is the query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61163/which-of-my-answers-have-helped-the-internet

This lists your answers in descending order of "most helpful" as defined by:

```
(views on question) / (# of answers)
```

Which can be significantly skewed by lot of answers. But you can fork the query to remove that factor.

---

A better query would be to weight it based on the score of your answer to the rest of the answers. There's lots of room to play around. Enjoy!
<sub>(I'd do this myself if I could. But I suck at SQL.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, it works good!